# How to eval a number into possible combinations

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a cleaver way to evaluate some numbers and set some properties. Each hex digit needs evaluated to see what it supports. given a number pattern ABCDEF here is what each digit supports.

- A = 8 Supports B, 4 Supports C, 2 Supports D, 1 Supports E, 0 nothing
- B = 8 Supports F, 4 Supports G, 2 Supports H, 1 Supports I, 0 nothing
- C = 8 Supports J, 4 Supports K, 2 Supports L, 1 Supports M, 0 nothing
- D = 8 Supports O, 4 Supports P, 2 Supports Q, 1 Supports R, 0 nothing
- E = 8 Supports S, 4 Supports T, 2 Supports U, 1 Supports V, 0 nothing
- F = 8 Supports W, 4 Supports X, 2 Supports Y, 1 Supports Z, 0 nothing

The supporting Letters B-Z are individual Booleans properties representing all possible supported items.

so, the number 0B6000 evaluated supports FHIKL, number 076000 supports KLMNO, and number 0B3000 supports FHIQR. My first thought was to get combinations of 8,4,2,1 then loop each digit checking a total of each combination.  Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: You're using jargon in this question which makes it difficult to ascertain what you're asking.

Comment: What does "supports" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What criteria do you have for "Clever" or "Easy"?

If you're good with string parsing and manipulation, you could get a list of supported values, as characters, using LINQ with some simple calculations:

```
Convert.ToString(int.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber), 2)
    .Reverse()
    .Select((v, i) => (v, i))
    .Where(e => e.v == '1')
    .Select(e => (char)('Z' - e.i - 1));
```

You could also declare a `Flags` `enum` with all of the supported items, and convert the value to a single value representing the sum of all those supported values.

```
[System.Flags]
public enum Supported{
    A = 1,       // or A = 1 << 0
    B = A << 1,  // or B = 1 << 1
    C = B << 1,  // or C = 1 << 2
    // ...
}
```

```
var supported = (Supported)uint.Parse(hex, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
Console.WriteLine(supported); // e.g. "A, B"
Console.WriteLine((supported | Supported.B) != 0); // e.g. "True"
```

Comment: The number given to me is the sum and I have to decode it.  So I'm given ie. 098000 
 and have to figure out what items are supported from that.  Each item, or letter in my question, is already set up as a bool property.  Will have to try the LINQ.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. So the `hex` variable is the string you're given `"098000"`. The LINQ statement I provided would give you an array of characters: `{'J', 'I', 'F'}`. The flag-enum solution would give you a "`Supported`"` value, whose ToString would produce `"F, I, J"`.

Comment: finally figured it all out and ended up using flags. thanks!